# How to get all ids of a list in a setParameter query?

Tags: sql, hql

The :ids is another query of id that i want to search, but i want that query to be executed for ALL ids and not just at least one of them

```
        def query= entityManager.createQuery("""
            select ip.id
            from EntitaProcesso ep
            join ep.istanzaProcesso ip
            where ep.id in(:ids)

        """).setParameter('ids',ids)
            .resultList
```

Comment: Is the question about the query above or the other query that you mention?

Comment: Do you want a SQL solution or a HQL/Hibernate solution?

Comment: i'm writing the query in HQL using Java classes

Comment: just use query as ids=select id from table name